# Can a UINavigationController contain a UITabbarController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uinavigationcontroller

I want to have a UIView inside of a NavigationController that has 4 buttons. Clicking on any of these 4 buttons will push a UITabBarController that contains a NavigationController with a respective UIView.

Is this possible? Tweetie seems to do something similar.

Comment: All the Apple docs and developer videos say quite strongly that tab bars should contain nav controllers, not the other way around.

Comment: I understand that, but some very popular apps such as Twitter and Facebook seem to get around this. I am designing my app similarly, and would like to replicate.

Comment: According to the responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249624/uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-design-advice, the Twitter and Facebook apps do it by rolling their own "tab bar" controls. Apple docs are very clear that you can't put a UITabBarController inside  NavigationController.

Comment: Is it possible to just use a UITabBar instead of rolling your own control? Also, a UITabBar doesn't have the "More" functionality that allows you to re-arrange items on the tab-bar.

Answer (score 1):

On my application, I have a tab bar view controller, then inside of that, I have navigation controllers going to individual views in my interface builder. I believe if you just copy this format, it will work.(-> means connected)

**Tab Bar View Controller->4 separate Navigation Controller->ui views**

I hope this helps