# Mixing UITableViewController and UITabBarController

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitableview

I want to combine `UITableViewController` and `UITabBarController`:

1) `UITableViewController` with navigation is shown 
2) `UITabBarController` is pushed 
(`[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];`), 
the tabbar is shown, `navigationItem` is invisible, but the `navigationBar` stays.

Is this possible? Is there an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you have a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController pushed onto it and you would like to push a UITabBarController on to the navigation stack as well.  If that is the case, then you may want to read [Apple's View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW11) where is states the following:

"Although a navigation controller can be embedded inside a tab, the reverse is not true. Presenting a tab bar interface from within a navigation interface is potentially confusing for users."

Having written that, there is a way to do it, but you must use a custom UIViewController instead of a UITabBarController.  This is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249624/uitabbarcontroller-uinavigationcontroller-design-advice)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do. I read this detailed discussion and now I understand why Apple does not want it to be implemented. I've to think about my UI-design and see if I can solve my problem with a different approach.